# How to get rid of warning "Unused variable: -----"?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to automate our software using python. here is sample of code:

```py
def parameters():
 
    wlocation = function_login.driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    wlocationlist = function_login.driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath').click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

it accepts and works fine however , there is a warning on the row # saying "Undefined variable: wlocation"

now I've tried to do this

```py
def parameters():
 
    wlocation = function_login.driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
    wlocation.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    wlocationlist = function_login.driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
    wlocationlist.click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

the warning disappear but when I run the code , it displays "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'"

PLEASE BEAR WITH ME IM NEW HERE THANKS SO MUCH FAM

Comment: maybe there is a missing import when I created a function ?

Comment: apparently, `wlocation` is a string so try printing it to see what it contains

Comment: you can also assign value to `_` if you don't want to use later.

Comment: or simply remove the assignment, that's the whole point of the warning